# NSTextView does not resize when subviews are added

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextview

In my OS X application I have a window with a split view which has 3 scrolling subviews.  In the far right subview I have a scroll view which contains a clip view which contains a text view.  When I add text to this NSTextView it resizes appropriately to fit the text, and when I scroll the window it changes the scrolling appropriately.

The problem arises when I add subviews to the NSTextView.  If I add a NSTextField to the NSTextView and it is beyond the bottom of the window the NSTextView will not resize so that I can see the NSTextField.

If I call setFrame on the NSTextView and resize it appropriately then I can scroll down to see the added view, BUT as soon as the window resizes the NSTextView "forgets" the frame that I set it to and no longer scrolls.

Why doesn't the NSTextView "remember" the frame size that I set it to after resizing the window?

Comment: are you using `auto layout` ?

Comment: No, I disabled it.  I've never worked with it before so I am just avoiding it.